# How can I clear the memory of an import file in python with a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have a while loop, and inside of if various import .py

As it is now, when it loops a second time, those import .py files, don't get imported again.

the .py file, creates a df, and makes a csv ... but when it loops, it doesnt import again that .py so it takes an old csv ...
I've tried making delete the csv, but the error is because it doesn't import the file.py in each loop.

Is there some way to make it import the files, each time it makes a loop?

If tried with `gc.collect()` and it doesn't work.

```
while (true):
    if a == 1:
        import d1makecsv
        df=pd.read_csv(d1)
        os.remove('d1.csv')
    if a == 2:
        import d2makecsv
        df=pd.read_csv(d2)
        os.remove('d2.csv')
    else:
        print("my mom is fat")
df_make_calcs=df
```

Comment: Is there a reason the imports are not at the top on the script? *Generally*, this is the way by which all imports should be handled.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `while` loop?  Nothing is changing inside the loop.   Imports at the top, prompt for an `a`, execute the associated statements, done.  No need for a loop.  (At least in the example provided)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```py
import importlib
importlib.reload(YOUR_MODULE)
```